# socket.gethostname() returning wrong host name

Tags: python, macos, sockets, hostname

When I was setting up my Macbook Pro I changed my hostname I guess to my name `Tristan`. I'm trying to work with sockets and call:

```
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

It is not giving me the error `socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

I'm assuming this is an issue because I have changed the name. If I type:

```
socket.gethostname('Tristan.local')
```

It actually prints out the correct ip address. My friend's Mac has not had the hostname changed and it returns the address of the network she is on. How do I change my hostname back to the local hostname or whatever I need to do in order to make:

```
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

Work again? I thought I was being fun at the time by changing it to my name but now I'm full of regret.

Comment: If your hostname doesn't have associated DNS you may not get an answer. That is if it's `martins-computer.local` or something like that DNS can't make sense of it. The host name is mostly decorative for systems that don't have fixed addresses. For servers with static IP addresses this is more reliable but even then their internal and external IP may differ dramatically because of firewall reasons.

Comment: so then is there a reason why on my friends computer it returns 'd-10-19-250-80.dhcp4.washington.edu' which I'm assuming is the address of our local network while mine simply returns the name?

Comment: In that case it looks like a name resolvable with DNS, so it'll work. Yours might not have an address like that. Some DHCP servers issue IPs with proper DNS names, but most do not. Universities are unusual in that they usually have thousands of IPs free for student use, but companies are on a much stricter IP budget.

Comment: So in that case what should I be doing for my code if I need to find the ip address I've attached to a server socket but can't find it through gethostbyname()?

Answer (score -2):

`gethostname` generally just reports what `/etc/hostname` or equivalent has in it, and that can be just a made up name. `gethostbyname` tries to resolve that name, and unless it's also in something like `/etc/hosts`, which some systems set up to match, and it's not resolvable by your configured DNS servers, then you get an error.

So you can try either fixing the name in `/etc/hosts` if it was there first under the old name, or you can ignore that and just use your host-name as-is.

Remember, unless your public and private IP match that DNS result is useless anyway. What you probably want is to hit a service like [Ipify](https://www.ipify.org) to determine what your actual external IP is.

Comment: so the DHCP address assigned to her is just a dynamic address she gets every time she connects to the school's network? Is there a way for me to find out what mine is or a reason that her laptop is returning the Dynamic address and mine is not?

Comment: The school's network issues actual DNS-resolvable addresses, so that's some really good work on the part of their network team. Most internal networks don't. You just get something like `192.168.2.11` and deal with it through NAT. You may be on a different network, or your configuration is overriding the name assignment. Windows, Linux and macOS handle this differently.

Comment: If you're going Mac to Mac, you can just use the Bonjour `.local` address directly, that should work, so `gethostname` is enough to get you a routable IP. Alternatively you can try and dig up what your local IP is, but the complication there is you may have several (wired, wireless, etc.)

Comment: This makes a lot more sense thank you. I think I'm still a little confused on why one laptop returns the DHCP and the other doesn't.

Comment: It could be MAC address affinity, or some other quirk of the DHCP. Try this on a different network, like a local coffee shop or library, and I bet you'd get the same results on both machines.